# Program doesn't run when using GDB watchpoint

Tags: c++, c, linux, gdb

For some reason, when I do a basic `watch var` and `run` in GDB, GDB just prints the `Starting program: blah blah` and nothing happens. GDB reports that `Hardware watchpoint 1: var`, so I don't think it's just being slow since hardware watchpoints are supposed to be fast and I ran it for a few minutes with no output.

When I `Ctrl-C` to abort I usually get an error like

```
dl_new_hash (s=0xf7e189d4 "0EE24_M_initialize_moneypunctEP15__locale_structPKc") at dl-lookup.c:577
577     dl-lookup.c: No such file or directory.
```

which to me seems like a error finding a shared lib? But GDB works fine with regular breakpoints, it's just watchpoints that are messing up.

My version is

```
$ gdb --version
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.2-18.el8
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Which looks similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64980070/gdb-stops-when-using-watchpoints-as-if-ctrl-z), but my program doesn't show any

```
[1]+  Stopped                 gdb MyProgram
```

there's no output at all.

Has anybody come across this?

Comment: Recommendation: Do what you can to can prove that the value you are expecting to change really did change in the time you spent waiting. Without it there really isn't much we can do for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, the variable I was trying to watch was a massive struct. I only had to watch a specific field of the struct, so I was able to basically just call `watch var.foo` and it worked fine. I'm rather surprised that GDB still marked it as a hardware watchpoint, but the more you know I guess.

Comment: The problem is that GDB doesn't know if it can actually place a h/w watchpoint until you start running the inferior.  By default GDB will assume it is placing a h/w watchpoint.  Once you start running and GDB actually tries to insert the watchpoint it realises there is not enough watchpoint registers and degrades to a s/w watchpoint.

If you first `start` the inferior, and then try to place the watchpoint on `var` GDB will immediately degrade to a s/w watchpoint.

It does feel like GDB should print a warning when degrading to a s/w watchpoint.

Comment: This question didn't result in a useful answer partially _because_ you didn't show what variable you were watching. If you want useful answers in the future, err no the side of providing _more_ info, not less.

Comment: @EmployedRussian agreed but company regulations mean I have to heavily mock all the code questions I ask here